# NAV2 cancel bt_action_node

Tags: ros2, nav2

In NAV2, I defined my own `on_cancelled` for my [bt_action_node](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L177).
Nevertheless, I realized it`s never called if [halt](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L299) (the method that cancels the action) is called.

The halt will set the tree to IDLE, but then the next [tick](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L189) will send a new goal, instead of processing the previously [cancelled](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/humble/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L283) goal.

How to make sure the on_cancelled is called in that case? Am I missing something here? Do I need to overrides the halt method as well to avoid the IDLE state before calling the `on_cancelled`?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I strongly recommend creating and sharing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancelling in action terms is when an external entity cancels the goal. This is a callback function that the cancelled state can be processed by the BT node in case it wants to populate / change the `BT::NodeStatus`. This is not called to cancel an action, but called once an action is already cancelled by an external agent (e.g. autonomy system or elsewhere in the BT using a cancel node) to potentially modify the BT status to send on the node's exit.

Halt is not cancel. While halt will cancel a goal when a BT is ending, that cancel is not an external cancel but an internal cancel to put the BT back into a neutral state - so there's no need for you to worry about messing with the `BT::NodeStatus` because the status is already set to `idle` by the halt process -- so there's no need to trigger this function.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. I was not aware of the expected internal/external cancels, but it does make sense. Thanks

Comment: No problem! Can you mark this as the right answer so folks know its complete?